# Phonegap 3 Custom plugin not working

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I've build an application 6 month ago with phonegap 2.6.0. My application works great. I want to update my application with phonegap 3. I use the CLI to create the project, I copy and paste all the files in the new project. I had with the CLI the needed basic plugin (device information, camera...). this work.

But now, I've custom plugin that I've written that I need to put in my new project.

My question is: Do I need to rewrite all my custom plugin in order to get it working with phonegap3? Is there a way to use my "older" plugin in phonegap 3?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to rewrite all my custom plugin in order to get it working
>   with phonegap3?

Yes, you will need to rewrite your plugin to use the new Cordova/phonegap. This is because a lot of things changed between how plugins interact with the main thread (on the native side) and how the JavaScript code is loaded into the page (now it uses require.js and AMD modules instead of just injecting the plugin code into `window.plugins` object.

> Is there a way to use my "older" plugin in phonegap 3?

Unfortunately, no, there is no way that I know of to use old plugins.

Hopefully it won't take that much effort to rewrite your plugin. There isn't a plugin upgrade guide yet but it is something that is needed - as you do this upgrade, feel free to take notes about what you needed to do and donate those notes back to the community. This would be a tremendous help in starting the plugin upgrade guide.

I'd recommend going through these two docs:

- [Android Plugins](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_platforms_android_plugin.md.html#Android%20Plugins)
- [Plugin Development Guide](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.2.0/guide_hybrid_plugins_index.md.html#Plugin%20Development%20Guide)

You could also probably look at the changelog for official Cordova plugins to see what they had to do between versions, but it might take some effort to determine the difference between bug fixes and updating the plugin code to work with new Cordova versions.